# How update application.properties in runtime Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need read a parameter from application.properties in the first interaction with one @RestController and save a new value in the same parameter, and i need make this in each interaction.

I searching in the documentation from Spring Boot but don't find nothing about this.

Comment: could you explain your use case a bit further? do you need to change it every request, or just after the first request? does your application only support 1 concurrent request? it seems like you might run into some threading issues with this too

Comment: Why do you need that? Can’t you read and write to a dedicated file?

Comment: @WillM. I need make this change it every request, this is the requirement but if you have a better idea i listen to it :)

Comment: @OleksandrShpota This was the requirement, but I can justify another solution.

Comment: @WillM. And yes this application only support 1 request from another application (Splunk).

Comment: This is very much not the idiomatic way to handle whatever it is you're trying to do (which is very unclear). This sounds like a job for an external datastore of some type.

Comment: You can use something like `AtomicInteger/AtomicBoolean` in one of your beans and on an external event to set the value. But if you really want to do that via app properties then you need to look at `spring-cloud-config`.

Comment: One Tip : If you want to modify the value of a particular key that you have in your application.properties, you can do it using the `Environment` bean. The environment bean would have all the properties loaded during startup and you can keep updating it. Altering the properties file and reloading it might not be a agreeable approach.